# Copy text from multiple fields, to another fields

Tags: jquery

I want to copty text from multiple textfields, to another textfields. I've tried, but it does not work. The value from the field fromtele, is only copied, not the other values.

Here is my HTML:

```
  echo "<form name=\"sendfrak\" action=\"frakthandling.php\" method=\"post\" />";
    echo "<div class=\"left2\"><h2>Fyll i uppgifter</h2>";
    echo "<h3>Från</h3>";
    echo "<div id='from'>";
    echo "<dl>";
    echo "<dt>Namn</dt><dd><input value=\"Net at Once Sweden AB\" type=\"text\" name=\"fromname\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Adress</dt><dd><input value=\"Box 177\" type=\"text\" name=\"fromaddr\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Postnr</dt><dd><input value=\"351 04\" type=\"text\" name=\"frompostnr\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Ort</dt><dd><input value=\"Växjö\" type=\"text\" name=\"fromort\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Telefon</dt><dd><input value=\"0771-404400\" type=\"text\" name=\"fromtele\" /></dd>";
    echo "</dl></div>";
    echo "<h3>Till</h3>";
    echo "<div id='rec'>";
    echo "<dl>";
    echo "<dt>Namn</dt><dd><input type=\"text\" name=\"toname\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Adress</dt><dd><input type=\"text\" name=\"toaddr\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Postnr</dt><dd><input type=\"text\" name=\"topostnr\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Ort</dt><dd><input type=\"text\" name=\"toort\" /></dd>";
    echo "</dl></div>";
    echo "<h3>Övrigt</h3>";
    echo "<dl>";
    echo "<dt>Referens</dt><dd><input type=\"text\" name=\"ref\" /> (har du inget kundnr, skriv t.ex. ärendenr eller personnr)</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Vikt</dt><dd><input value=\"1\" type=\"text\" name=\"weight\" /></dd>";
    echo "<dt>Innehåll</dt><dd><input value=\"Elektronik\" type=\"text\" name=\"content\" /></dd>";
    echo "</dl>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"do_send\" value=\"Skriv ut\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"do_download\" value=\"PDF\" />"; if(isset($_GET['pdf'])) { echo "<a href='" . $_GET['pdf'] . "' style='margin-left: 10px;'>Ladda ned PDF</a>"; }
     echo "<a href='' id='change'>Skifa</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
```

Here is my jQuery that i've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#change').click(function() {
        $("#from input").each(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();

            $('#rec input').each(function() {
                $(this).val(value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have the `$('#rec input').each` nested inside the `#from`.  When the last input is read (fromtele), it is copied to every `#rec input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that, you are getting each input value from the #from and setting it to all the inputs in #rec, due to which only the last input's value would be set for all #rec inputs.

Try the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#change').click(function() {
            var inputValues = [];
            $("#from input").each(function() {
                inputValues.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#rec input').each(function(index) {
                if(index < inputValues.length) {
                    $(this).val(inputValues[index]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

How do I remove all the textcontents in the first fields, after the text has been copied? I've tried $("#from input").empty(); but that does not work.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it with $("#form input").val("");

Answer (score 0):

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [.index(element)](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rec = $('#rec input'), //cache selectors 
        from_input = $("#from input");
    $('#change').click(function () {
        var arr = from_input.map(function () {  //create array of all values
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        rec.val(function () {
            return arr[$(this).index('input')]; //get index of current element and get it's value from array arr
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second .each() is iterating through all of the inputs in #rec div, not just one.

You should split this out like so:

```
var value = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#change').click(function() {
        $("#from input").each(function(i) {
            value[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        $('#rec input').each(function(i) {
            $(this).val(value[i]);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your markup, I came up with this solution.

```
$("#from input").blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var fromName = $(this).attr('name');
    var toName = fromName.replace('from', 'to');

    $('input[name="' + toName + '"]').val(value);
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/xeLCm/